# How do I abort stop jobs?

Tags: shutdown

Sometimes a stop job keeps Ubuntu from shutting down.

In many cases that I know that it's safe to terminate the process that's responsible for that stop job. In such cases how do I just "abort" that stop job? How do I quickly just terminate that process when I see its stop job?

I **don't** want a process-specific solution nor do I want to reduce the waiting time.

Comment: You could use the [Magic SysRq kernel commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) to immediately shut the system off. This is like a roundhouse kick though as it does not distinguish between processes. Maybe not exactly what you want.

Comment: yes not exactly. I want to just terminate that process. But this is also useful. I can use it till I get an answer (if ever LOL) thx X') @ByteCommander